# Extracting specific information from text

Tags: python, nltk

I'd like to get some data from text file. I've decided to do it using [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/book), but I'm open to suggestions if there is a better way to do this.

Here is an example:

> I need a flight from New York NY to San Francisco CA.

From this text, I'd like to get city and state for origin and destination.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import nltk
from nltk.text import *
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader

def readfiles():    
    corpus_root = 'C:\prototype\emails'
    w = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
    t = Text(w.words())
    print "--- to ----"
    print t.concordance("to")

    print "--- from ----"
    print t.concordance("from")
```

I can read the text from some input (file in my case) then use [concordance method](http://nltk.github.com/_modules/nltk/text.html#Text.concordance) to find all the usages of it.  I want to extract the city, state information that comes after 'to' and 'from'.

Question is what is the best way to look at text that is after the instances of 'to' and 'from'?

Comment: Picking out places like this from text is known as "Named Entity Recognition" - NLTK can do this, although you might want to adapt your own version based on a gazetteer (GeoNames.org is probably work a look for data).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're better off reading the file in line by line?
Then something as simple as:

```
cityState = dataAfterTo.split(",")
city = cityState[0]
state = cityState[1].split()[0]
```

Unless you're dealing with user generated content of course.

Comment: Yeah, its user generated. So there may or may not be a ',' separating city and state. I'm hoping to find more elegant solution using python language or library.